# Recorrer Array con Object dentro, PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente Array en PHP:

```
array(4) { 
    ["moduleName"]=> string(8) "Products" 
    ["id"]=> string(6) "14x937" 
    ["user"]=> object(Users)#523 (99) {} 
    ["data"]=> array(40) {} 
}
```

Lo intento recorrer de todas las maneras posibles, como:

```
foreach ($Arraytotal as $key => $value) {
   echo $key.'-'.$value.'<br>';
   var_dump($key);
}
```

Pero solo obtengo los datos hasta el segundo componente del arreglo, los datos que necesito están en Arraytotal['data'], no se como poder llegar a ello.

Gracias.

Comment: Ok, viendo mejor el `var_dump` se ve más claro. Puedes hacer esto: `$arrDatos=$Arraytotal["data"];` y luego recorres `$arrDatos` como estás haciendo en tu código. Algo así: `foreach ($arrDatos as $k=>$v){ "echo key: $k / value: $v".PHP_EOL;}` Puedes verificar la estructura con `var_dump($arrDatos);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según el `var_dump` que muestras, en la clave `data` de `$Arraytotal` hay un array.

Entonces, puedes acceder a ese array buscando esa clave directamente, por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($Arraytotal["data"] as $key => $value) {
     echo $key.'-'.$value.'<br>';
     var_dump($key);
}
```

O bien puedes sacarlo aparte y recorrerlo:

```
$arrDatos=$Arraytotal["data"];
var_dump($arrDatos);

foreach ($arrDatos as $key => $value) {
     echo $key.'-'.$value.PHP_EOL;
     var_dump($key);
}
```

---

#### EDIT:

Para acceder al objeto que hay en `user`, puedes crear una referencia, igual que como hiciste antes:

```
$objUser=$Arraytotal["user"];
var_dump($objUser);
```

Y luego leerlo según las propiedades que tenga, la diferencia aquí es que, a las propiedades de los objetos se accede usando `->propiedad`, no como en los arrays qye se accede `["propiedad"]`.

O sea, si tu objeto tiene por ejemplo una propiedad `nombre`, sólo haces esto:

```
echo $objUser->nombre;
```

También se pueden convertir a array, pero si es sólo para su lectura no vale la pena.